# Mongoengine: Querying using __not__contains but with lists instead of string

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have a list of topics that I want to filter out from 'title' field in  News Database.

I want the solution to do the opposite of what `__contains` does, but contains works with string, and I want to give it a list in which it will filter out every news that will contain the words given in the list.

Example:

`blacklist=["Facebook", "Apple"]`

I want to use this list and filter out every news if its title contains words in `blacklist`.

Edit: I think I didn't clarify my objective in above lines.
Using `blacklist` declared above, in a list of news, exclude all news that 'contains' words in `blacklist`. (NOTE: I want to solve it using 'list' because this list i.e. `blacklist` might contain a lot of words.)

e.g.
"Facebook is not privacy friendly" = excluded

"Apple may be privacy friendly" = excluded

"Bitcoin market crashed" = not excluded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine multiple conditions with AND/OR through MongoEngine's [Q class](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html?highlight=Q%20#advanced-queries)

```
from mongoengine import connect, Document, StringField, Q

connect()

class TestDoc(Document):
    s = StringField()


TestDoc(s="Facebook is this").save()
TestDoc(s="and Twitter is that").save()
TestDoc(s="Something else").save()

query = Q(s__contains="Facebook") | Q(s__contains="Twitter")
TestDoc.objects(query)    # finds the 2 objects

# or dynamically from a list...
my_fancy_list = ['Facebook', 'Twitter']
dynamic_query = Q(s__contains=my_fancy_list.pop())
while my_fancy_list:
    dynamic_query |= Q(s__contains=my_fancy_list.pop())

TestDoc.objects(dynamic_query)    # finds the 2 objects
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Well... You're right in your answer, but that is a bit different from my objective. I've clarified in original question. So... what `contains` keywords does is it takes two string arguments, and finds first string in second string. like finding "Apple" in "Apple might be privacy friendly". But here, I'm not giving it a string i.e. "Apple", I'm giving it ["Apple", "Facebook"] and it should find if any of the given word/string appears in given second string. Now, excluding/including is another matter, currently I want just to make a filter for them...

Comment: ok I think I got it, I've changed the answer to match this

Comment: Dude... You're again right... But there is more to this problem. I want to do it using a list. My list won't contain just these words, there might be many words, and there might be no words...

Comment: Just use as many Q(s__contains=you_string) as you have item in the list... You can build it dynamically obviously

Comment: Hey, I finally got the reputation enough to upvote your answer... Thanks for helping me back then. :)